# User account mapped to SELinux staff_u account but unable to run sudo command

Tags: centos, selinux

I have two user accounts in my virtual machine, `anim` and `anim2`. Both are part of the `wheel` group and can run su/sudo commands.

I was reading on [redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-targeted_policy-confined_and_unconfined_users) how SELinux user staff_u can only run `sudo` commands and not `su` so I changed anim2 from `unconfined_u` to `staff_u` via

`sudo semanage login -a -s staff_u anim2` and now here's the output of `sudo semanage login -l`

```
Login Name           SELinux User         MLS/MCS Range        Service

__default__          unconfined_u         s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
anim2                staff_u              s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
root                 unconfined_u         s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
system_u             system_u             s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
```

After a reboot, I login to anim2 account via GNOME login screen and check my security context.

```
[anim2@localhost ~]$ id -Z
staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

But unfortunately, I'm unable to run sudo commands with anim2 user. I get permission denied and I can see the errors in `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

Here's the error message from `/var/log/messages`

```
Feb  6 16:23:07 localhost setroubleshoot: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/sudo from read 
access on the file stat. For complete SELinux messages run: 
sealert -l da20696b-791b-4585-b69b-28d2b65c2936
Feb  6 16:23:07 localhost python: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/sudo from read 
access on the file stat.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) 
suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that sudo should 
be allowed read access on the stat file by default.#012Then you should report 
this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 
'sudo' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sudo#012# semodule -i my-sudo.pp#012
```

And here's the error message from `sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log`

```
If you believe that ls should have the dac_override capability by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'ls' --raw | audit2allow -M my-ls
# semodule -i my-ls.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
Target Context                staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
Target Objects                Unknown [ capability ]
Source                        ls
Source Path                   /usr/bin/ls
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          <Unknown>
Source RPM Packages           coreutils-8.22-23.el7.x86_64
Target RPM Packages           
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     localhost.localdomain
Platform                      Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
                              #1 SMP Thu Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   6
First Seen                    2019-02-06 15:52:53 PST
Last Seen                     2019-02-06 16:21:52 PST
Local ID                      de276963-e626-4336-89b4-2701788f3222

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1549498912.128:409): avc:  denied  { dac_override } for  pid=10279 
comm="ls" capability=1  scontext=staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 
tcontext=staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=capability permissive=0


type=AVC msg=audit(1549498912.128:409): avc:  denied  { dac_read_search } for  
pid=10279 comm="ls" capability=2  scontext=staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 
tcontext=staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=capability permissive=0


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1549498912.128:409): arch=x86_64 syscall=openat success=no 
exit=EACCES a0=ffffffffffffff9c a1=acac10 a2=90800 a3=0 items=0 ppid=10276 pid=10279 
auid=1001 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts2 ses=8 
comm=ls exe=/usr/bin/ls subj=staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)

Hash: ls,staff_t,staff_t,capability,dac_override
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's an output of SELinux booleans

```
[root@localhost audit]# getsebool -a
abrt_anon_write --> off
abrt_handle_event --> off
abrt_upload_watch_anon_write --> on
antivirus_can_scan_system --> off
antivirus_use_jit --> off
auditadm_exec_content --> on
authlogin_nsswitch_use_ldap --> off
authlogin_radius --> off
authlogin_yubikey --> off
awstats_purge_apache_log_files --> off
boinc_execmem --> on
cdrecord_read_content --> off
cluster_can_network_connect --> off
cluster_manage_all_files --> off
cluster_use_execmem --> off
cobbler_anon_write --> off
cobbler_can_network_connect --> off
cobbler_use_cifs --> off
cobbler_use_nfs --> off
collectd_tcp_network_connect --> off
condor_tcp_network_connect --> off
conman_can_network --> off
conman_use_nfs --> off
container_connect_any --> off
cron_can_relabel --> off
cron_system_cronjob_use_shares --> off
cron_userdomain_transition --> on
cups_execmem --> off
cvs_read_shadow --> off
daemons_dump_core --> off
daemons_enable_cluster_mode --> off
daemons_use_tcp_wrapper --> off
daemons_use_tty --> off
dbadm_exec_content --> on
dbadm_manage_user_files --> off
dbadm_read_user_files --> off
deny_execmem --> off
deny_ptrace --> off
dhcpc_exec_iptables --> off
dhcpd_use_ldap --> off
domain_can_mmap_files --> on
domain_can_write_kmsg --> off
domain_fd_use --> on
domain_kernel_load_modules --> off
entropyd_use_audio --> on
exim_can_connect_db --> off
exim_manage_user_files --> off
exim_read_user_files --> off
fcron_crond --> off
fenced_can_network_connect --> off
fenced_can_ssh --> off
fips_mode --> on
ftpd_anon_write --> off
ftpd_connect_all_unreserved --> off
ftpd_connect_db --> off
ftpd_full_access --> off
ftpd_use_cifs --> off
ftpd_use_fusefs --> off
ftpd_use_nfs --> off
ftpd_use_passive_mode --> off
git_cgi_enable_homedirs --> off
git_cgi_use_cifs --> off
git_cgi_use_nfs --> off
git_session_bind_all_unreserved_ports --> off
git_session_users --> off
git_system_enable_homedirs --> off
git_system_use_cifs --> off
git_system_use_nfs --> off
gitosis_can_sendmail --> off
glance_api_can_network --> off
glance_use_execmem --> off
glance_use_fusefs --> off
global_ssp --> off
gluster_anon_write --> off
gluster_export_all_ro --> off
gluster_export_all_rw --> on
gluster_use_execmem --> off
gpg_web_anon_write --> off
gssd_read_tmp --> on
guest_exec_content --> on
haproxy_connect_any --> off
httpd_anon_write --> off
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on
httpd_can_check_spam --> off
httpd_can_connect_ftp --> off
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> off
httpd_can_connect_mythtv --> off
httpd_can_connect_zabbix --> off
httpd_can_network_connect --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off
httpd_can_network_memcache --> off
httpd_can_network_relay --> off
httpd_can_sendmail --> off
httpd_dbus_avahi --> off
httpd_dbus_sssd --> off
httpd_dontaudit_search_dirs --> off
httpd_enable_cgi --> on
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
httpd_enable_homedirs --> off
httpd_execmem --> off
httpd_graceful_shutdown --> on
httpd_manage_ipa --> off
httpd_mod_auth_ntlm_winbind --> off
httpd_mod_auth_pam --> off
httpd_read_user_content --> off
httpd_run_ipa --> off
httpd_run_preupgrade --> off
httpd_run_stickshift --> off
httpd_serve_cobbler_files --> off
httpd_setrlimit --> off
httpd_ssi_exec --> off
httpd_sys_script_anon_write --> off
httpd_tmp_exec --> off
httpd_tty_comm --> off
httpd_unified --> off
httpd_use_cifs --> off
httpd_use_fusefs --> off
httpd_use_gpg --> off
httpd_use_nfs --> off
httpd_use_openstack --> off
httpd_use_sasl --> off
httpd_verify_dns --> off
icecast_use_any_tcp_ports --> off
irc_use_any_tcp_ports --> off
irssi_use_full_network --> off
kdumpgui_run_bootloader --> off
keepalived_connect_any --> off
kerberos_enabled --> on
ksmtuned_use_cifs --> off
ksmtuned_use_nfs --> off
logadm_exec_content --> on
logging_syslogd_can_sendmail --> off
logging_syslogd_run_nagios_plugins --> off
logging_syslogd_use_tty --> on
login_console_enabled --> on
logrotate_read_inside_containers --> off
logrotate_use_nfs --> off
logwatch_can_network_connect_mail --> off
lsmd_plugin_connect_any --> off
mailman_use_fusefs --> off
mcelog_client --> off
mcelog_exec_scripts --> on
mcelog_foreground --> off
mcelog_server --> off
minidlna_read_generic_user_content --> off
mmap_low_allowed --> off
mock_enable_homedirs --> off
mount_anyfile --> on
mozilla_plugin_bind_unreserved_ports --> off
mozilla_plugin_can_network_connect --> off
mozilla_plugin_use_bluejeans --> off
mozilla_plugin_use_gps --> off
mozilla_plugin_use_spice --> off
mozilla_read_content --> off
mpd_enable_homedirs --> off
mpd_use_cifs --> off
mpd_use_nfs --> off
mplayer_execstack --> off
mysql_connect_any --> off
nagios_run_pnp4nagios --> off
nagios_run_sudo --> off
nagios_use_nfs --> off
named_tcp_bind_http_port --> off
named_write_master_zones --> off
neutron_can_network --> off
nfs_export_all_ro --> on
nfs_export_all_rw --> on
nfsd_anon_write --> off
nis_enabled --> off
nscd_use_shm --> on
openshift_use_nfs --> off
openvpn_can_network_connect --> on
openvpn_enable_homedirs --> on
openvpn_run_unconfined --> off
pcp_bind_all_unreserved_ports --> off
pcp_read_generic_logs --> off
piranha_lvs_can_network_connect --> off
polipo_connect_all_unreserved --> off
polipo_session_bind_all_unreserved_ports --> off
polipo_session_users --> off
polipo_use_cifs --> off
polipo_use_nfs --> off
polyinstantiation_enabled --> off
postfix_local_write_mail_spool --> on
postgresql_can_rsync --> off
postgresql_selinux_transmit_client_label --> off
postgresql_selinux_unconfined_dbadm --> on
postgresql_selinux_users_ddl --> on
pppd_can_insmod --> off
pppd_for_user --> off
privoxy_connect_any --> on
prosody_bind_http_port --> off
puppetagent_manage_all_files --> off
puppetmaster_use_db --> off
racoon_read_shadow --> off
radius_use_jit --> off
redis_enable_notify --> off
rpcd_use_fusefs --> off
rsync_anon_write --> off
rsync_client --> off
rsync_export_all_ro --> off
rsync_full_access --> off
samba_create_home_dirs --> off
samba_domain_controller --> off
samba_enable_home_dirs --> off
samba_export_all_ro --> off
samba_export_all_rw --> off
samba_load_libgfapi --> off
samba_portmapper --> off
samba_run_unconfined --> off
samba_share_fusefs --> off
samba_share_nfs --> off
sanlock_enable_home_dirs --> off
sanlock_use_fusefs --> off
sanlock_use_nfs --> off
sanlock_use_samba --> off
saslauthd_read_shadow --> off
secadm_exec_content --> on
secure_mode --> off
secure_mode_insmod --> off
secure_mode_policyload --> off
selinuxuser_direct_dri_enabled --> on
selinuxuser_execheap --> off
selinuxuser_execmod --> on
selinuxuser_execstack --> on
selinuxuser_mysql_connect_enabled --> off
selinuxuser_ping --> on
selinuxuser_postgresql_connect_enabled --> off
selinuxuser_rw_noexattrfile --> on
selinuxuser_share_music --> off
selinuxuser_tcp_server --> off
selinuxuser_udp_server --> off
selinuxuser_use_ssh_chroot --> off
sge_domain_can_network_connect --> off
sge_use_nfs --> off
smartmon_3ware --> off
smbd_anon_write --> off
spamassassin_can_network --> off
spamd_enable_home_dirs --> on
spamd_update_can_network --> off
squid_connect_any --> on
squid_use_tproxy --> off
ssh_chroot_rw_homedirs --> off
ssh_keysign --> off
ssh_sysadm_login --> off
staff_exec_content --> on
staff_use_svirt --> off
swift_can_network --> off
sysadm_exec_content --> on
telepathy_connect_all_ports --> off
telepathy_tcp_connect_generic_network_ports --> on
tftp_anon_write --> off
tftp_home_dir --> off
tmpreaper_use_cifs --> off
tmpreaper_use_nfs --> off
tmpreaper_use_samba --> off
tomcat_can_network_connect_db --> off
tomcat_read_rpm_db --> off
tomcat_use_execmem --> off
tor_bind_all_unreserved_ports --> off
tor_can_network_relay --> off
unconfined_chrome_sandbox_transition --> on
unconfined_login --> on
unconfined_mozilla_plugin_transition --> on
unprivuser_use_svirt --> off
use_ecryptfs_home_dirs --> off
use_fusefs_home_dirs --> off
use_lpd_server --> off
use_nfs_home_dirs --> off
use_samba_home_dirs --> off
user_exec_content --> on
varnishd_connect_any --> off
virt_read_qemu_ga_data --> off
virt_rw_qemu_ga_data --> off
virt_sandbox_use_all_caps --> on
virt_sandbox_use_audit --> on
virt_sandbox_use_fusefs --> off
virt_sandbox_use_mknod --> off
virt_sandbox_use_netlink --> off
virt_sandbox_use_sys_admin --> off
virt_transition_userdomain --> off
virt_use_comm --> off
virt_use_execmem --> off
virt_use_fusefs --> off
virt_use_glusterd --> off
virt_use_nfs --> off
virt_use_rawip --> off
virt_use_samba --> off
virt_use_sanlock --> off
virt_use_usb --> on
virt_use_xserver --> off
webadm_manage_user_files --> off
webadm_read_user_files --> off
wine_mmap_zero_ignore --> off
xdm_bind_vnc_tcp_port --> off
xdm_exec_bootloader --> off
xdm_sysadm_login --> off
xdm_write_home --> off
xen_use_nfs --> off
xend_run_blktap --> on
xend_run_qemu --> on
xguest_connect_network --> on
xguest_exec_content --> on
xguest_mount_media --> on
xguest_use_bluetooth --> on
xserver_clients_write_xshm --> off
xserver_execmem --> off
xserver_object_manager --> off
zabbix_can_network --> off
zabbix_run_sudo --> off
zarafa_setrlimit --> off
zebra_write_config --> off
zoneminder_anon_write --> off
zoneminder_run_sudo --> off
```

Here's some info on the CentOS machine I'm running.

`3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64`

`CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`

And `sestatus`

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-selinux-on-centos-7-part-3-users).

Comment: You have to configure sudo, that tutorial uses su .  see http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/selinux-and-confined-users/ or similar

Comment: The user is in the wheel group which has ALL=(ALL) ALL in the sudoers file. I guess that's not enough? So I applied the change in the sudoers file from the link and it works! Does that mean the user can also have the security of staff_u, unconfined_r, unconfined_t ?

Comment: And according to RHEL's website, staff_u only has sudo access and not su, in my case my user was unable to run su but could run sudo. I did however notice that I could run sudo su, which switched me to root and then I could run su. Is that supposed to happen? Seems like a loop hole.

Comment: Staff_u has sudo access, but root access is confined by selinux to staff_u . The mod you made allows staff_u to transition to unconfirmed